# Clear individual form fields/widgets data with button

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

Is there a way to clear form fields/widgets data with react-json-schema-form?

Here is the link for react json schema - [reactJsonSchema](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[reactJsonSchemaPlayGround](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/)

Comment: I am assuming you want to clear the data in the form on click of a button? Looking at the documentation, I see form event handlers, which could be used to achieve this, right?

Comment: I wanted to clear individual fields data , not the entire form data. We can reset the entire form data by setting the formState with defaults. I was looking for more granular resets. Like for eg. If we have two input fields, i wanted a clear button for both, which will clear the field or set it to default.
I found a work around where we can create our own widgets with clear button, and onClick of the button we can clear/reset the form fields. Not sure if this is an elegant solution though.

Comment: I Was looking for something like this [Clear Button For each form fields](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/pull/472).